# What is the Domain(in ref to Domain Driven Design) of a Software product company?

Tags: dns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I was promoted recently as a software architect in a Software development company that produces an Enterprise Content Management product for a customer segment that includes the likes of Insurance companies, Healthcare companies, Research companies and Government agencies.

I had designed moderately complex applications at this organization and my previous jobs.

As a new architect I want to explore Domain Driven Design concepts and various architecture types for migration of our product to a cloud service provider and metamorphize our product from a media based deployment to Software as Service (SAAS) offering.

In my opinion to do this correctly, I will need to create a domain model from the domain for which the software is written.

However the problem I am having is determining what the domain for a product software company is when their products caters to varying needs of disparate customer verticals. I suspect the domain is some kind of meta-domain and not a regular business domain like shipping, insurance or healthcare.

I have following question for this scenario

**Question:** In terms of Domain Driven Development, what would be the domain of such a company and how can I articulate it so, I can create a domain model?

Comment: What does the software do? What goals does it solve and how?

Comment: It is an ECM software, so at the core it does document management i.e. storage, classification, tagging and retrieval of documents in digital format. This core capability of the software is further enhanced by value added features like Workflow management, Case management and Capture and Scanning (i.e. convert non-digital and digital documents into the format required by our ECM to do its function). Then there are modules that provide integrations with disparate systems like ERPs, Domain specific application etc.. There is more, but this is good enough to explain what the software is doing.

Comment: Well, I think you just named a few sub-domains of your software domain ;)

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the Core Domain can be tricky because the **core** purpose of your software application can be obfuscated because of all the **supporting** features that need to be present to make the application useful.

These clues may help you identify and categorize functionality between your Core Domain and Supporting Domains:

- Is your software no longer identifiable from a product outside your domain category if you remove a piece of the functionality? You are dealing with a **Core Domain**.
- What is your company's Vision/Mission/Differentiator Statement? They usually reveal the **Core Domain**.
- What category are you and your competitors grouped into in industry reports like Gartner provided? That is your **Core Domain**.
- If your product addresses different customer domains, what common features are used by almost all of them? That is your **Core Domain**.
- Is functionality an industry standard? Does everybody else have it too? Instead of building it, can you buy software off-the-shelf and integrate it into your application, if one were available? If yes, you are dealing with a **Supporting Domain**.
- If you were to remove some functionality because customers do not use it or don't value it enough, would your product still be marketable? That is a **Supporting Domain**.

Answering these questions will point you in the right direction, but the boundaries of your core domain can be unique to your product's value proposition. Don't hesitate to expand and contract the core domain as the product grows and matures.

Most importantly, talk to your Domain Experts and Salespeople. They usually have a very good idea of what the product pitch is, what is the core value, and what are addons.

Comment: You can also use the Whirlpool process of Model Exploration to explore models: https://www.domainlanguage.com/ddd/whirlpool/